# .NET Core 2.0 Console App - Can you create appsettings.json transformations

Tags: console-application, transform, appsettings

I have a .NET Core 2.0 console app with an appsettings.json.  I tried to create a appsettings.staging.json file, but it doesn't get "nested" like it would in a ASPNET Core web app.

I can't seem to figure out how/if Core 2.0 console applications have support for appsettings.json transformations.

Any thoughts?